# Updating some row values in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which I want to merge into another dataframe, but only to affect specific cells rather than a whole row.

Old dataframe:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2|  bb|  bc|
## +---+----+----+
```

New dataframe:

```
## +---+----+
## |key|val1|
## +---+----+
## |  2| bbb|
## +---+----+
```

Result:

```
## +---+----+----+
## |key|val1|val2|
## +---+----+----+
## |  1|  aa|  ab|
## |  2| bbb|  bc|
## +---+----+----+
```

The key is unique in this case so the row to be affected will always be identifiable. The old dataframe will also always contain the keys from the new dataframe.

As dataframes are immutable I'll have to call `withColumn` to create a new one, presumably by passing in some sort of UDF, but I'm a bit lost when it comes to what that UDF should contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an outer join to get the expected output :

```
scala> val oldDf = Seq((1, "aa", "ab"), (2, "bb", "bc")).toDF("key", "val1", "val2").as("old")
// oldDf: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [key: int, val1: string ... 1 more field]
scala> val newDf = Seq((2, "bbb")).toDF("key", "val1").as("new")
// newDf: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [key: int, val1: string]

scala> oldDf.join(newDf, Seq("key"), "outer").select($"key", coalesce($"new.val1", $"old.val1").alias("val1"), $"val2").show
// +---+----+----+
// |key|val1|val2|
// +---+----+----+
// |  1|  aa|  ab| 
// |  2| bbb|  bc|
// +---+----+----+
```

**Note:** `coalesce` will select the first not null value between `new.val1` and `old.val1`.

Comment: what if i want to sum of two values from newdf can i simply add both the columns in the coalesce ??

Comment: what do you mean by 'first not null value' ??

Comment: @SundeepPidugu That means **if `new.val1` is not null**, the value for `key` will be `new.val1`, **otherwise if `old.val1` is not null**, the value for `key` will be `old.val1`, **otherwise** the value of `key` will be null. This is basic SQL dialect.

Comment: So i want to replace the column with a sum of columns in new Df then i have to pass it as the first parameter in coalesce to reflect the values right ?

Comment: That should do.

Comment: It works like magic to me! ^^ In Databricks though I had to call the columns like this: oldDf("val1")

Comment: Glad to hear that @Eva :)

Comment: What if the datasets have many columns? Do I need to specify each in the select? Is there no other way? Is there no way to directly update the row we want?